# Electron: __ was compiled against a different version of Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-packager

When trying to package electron app on macOS Sierra using electron-installer-dmg, I get the following:

```
Error: The module '/Users/august/projects/node_modules/macos-alias/build/Release/volume.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 54. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)<br>
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)<br>
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)<br>
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)<br>
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)<br>
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)<br>
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/august/projects/node_modules/macos-alias/lib/create.js:7:13)<br>
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)<br>
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)<br>
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)<br>
```

Versions:

```
Node 8.0.0
npm: 5.4
electron: 1.7.5
electron-installer-dmg: 0.2.1
electron-packager: 8.7.2
macos-alias: 0
```

I've tried:

- Switching node versions.
- Running `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild`
- Removing node_modules and running `npm install`
- Running `npm cache clear` and the re-installing packages
- Running `npm rebuild`
- Setting .npmrc file:

  ```
  runtime = electron
  target = 1.7.5
  target_arch = x64
  disturl = https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
  ```

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: yes @JaromandaX

Comment: I've just updated the list. yes @JaromandaX I've tried that

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: @niba I did few things that solved it.
Make sure you run the builder from inside `package.json`
If that doesn't work, I manually went inside the folders in node_modules and ran `node-gyp` rebuild

Answer (score 1):

Electron **1.7.5** uses:

- **Node: 7.9.0**
- Chromium: 58.0.3029.110
- V8: 5.8.283.38

Only packages compiled with the **same version** of Node will work. Try downgrading your Node version to 7.9 (you can find the installer [here](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v7.9.0/)) and try the whole process from the start.

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: @August Are you sure you are using the same version? Had the same issue and that's the way I resolved it.

Comment: I've downgraded version to 7.9. What seems to have worked is going to the folder in node_modules and running `node-gyp rebuild` manually

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `electron-builder` to build your electron project. You need to run this command `electron-builder install-app-deps`

Add this command into scripts of package.json to ensure your native dependencies are always matched electron version.

```
{
    "scripts": {
       "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    }
}
```